# Why pull-ing not always causes conflict, if there is difference between local and remote files?

Tags: git, github

Suppose there is 2 collaborators on github for one repository, user1 and user2.

let's say both of users share file with exactly same condition at this point.

Then user1 made changes in file locally, then: `git add file.txt` then `git commit -m'some comment here'` and then `git push`. Now, file is updated on github repository too.

Then, user2 does: `git pull`. file is downloaded (and updated locally) for user2 without any conflict. Why there is no conflict?

I expected that after every `pull`, if there is difference between local and remote files, conflict should be happen. What  I'm  misunderstood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're making a confusion between "difference" and "conflict".

Conflicts are a subset of differences.

Some differences are straightforward enough for git to assume what's to do. One file is added, one line is added in an existing file, some chunk is removed. All right.

Conflicts, in the other hand, occur when both parties have diverged from their last common state.

Let's imagine a repo with a `file.txt` which, at commit `B`, contains the following text :

```
Here is the first line.
Here is the second.
And my uncle is evil.
```

and we assume that simple history

```
A---B---C <<< branch1
     \
      D <<< branch2
```

Here, if commit `C` modifies the first line of `file.txt` to

```
Here are the first words.
```

But in `D` the same line is modified differently, let's say

```
Here is the first line. And some words.
```

Then git can't figure out which version (or a mix of both) is to be taken, so it interrupts its operation and lets you handle it manually to give the user control over the end result.

---

So to return to your specific question and the `pull` command, it's rather rare in most workflows since stable branches which are regularly updated via pull are rarely directly commited on directly, rather merged into from a feature branch.

Comment: Disclaimer : My uncle is *not* evil. :-)